# Remove ? from url in wordpress .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to remove the ? from the url using .htaccess file.

Current: domain.com/profile/?username/about

Expected: domain.com/profile/username/about

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is the following rules.

RewriteCond 
RewriteRule